# JWrapper: error when signing OSX App 'NoSuchAliasException'

Tags: macos, jwrapper

I'm trying to sign my JWrapper OSX App following these instructions:
http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-code-signing.html

I created a Developer ID, exported the 3 certificates, and created a P12 store. But I'm not sure which ID I'm supposed to give here:

```
<DeveloperIdAlias>your developer ID (typically 'developers name dev key')</DeveloperIdAlias>
```

Which ID is this exactly and where can I find it? I tried everything I could find (my name, Apple ID, user ID key, 'organizational unit' key, another 10-digit key that appears besides my name when I click on my mac developer certificate in keychain)... In each case, I get this error:

```
[MacOS] Signing OSX App
**********************************
*          BUILD FAILED          *
**********************************
** Error Trace:

utils.buildtools.common.signing.KeyStoreDetails$NoSuchAliasException: Unable to find alias 'KL596QNCVZ'
    at utils.buildtools.common.signing.KeyStoreDetails.loadKeyStore(KeyStoreDetails.java:88)
    at utils.buildtools.common.signing.KeyStoreDetails.<init>(KeyStoreDetails.java:40)
    at utils.buildtools.osx.signer.MacSigner.initialiseCertificate(MacSigner.java:639)
    at utils.buildtools.osx.signer.MacSigner.signApp(MacSigner.java:794)
    at jwrapper.JWrapperCompiler.main(JWrapperCompiler.java:2468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at SecureRunner2.<init>(SecureRunner2.java:452)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at SecureRunner1.<init>(SecureRunner1.java:422)
    at SecureRunner1.<init>(SecureRunner1.java:227)
    at SecureRunner1.main(SecureRunner1.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at jwrapper.launch.JWCompiler.main(JWCompiler.java:112)
** Reason: utils.buildtools.common.signing.KeyStoreDetails$NoSuchAliasException: Unable to find alias 'KL596QNCVZ'
```

EDIT: I had put the certificates and the p12 in a directory and provided the paths as required. Note that the key provided for the developer ID alias is the one that appears in the error message, and as mentioned above, I tried a bunch of different things for this field but always get the same error:

```
<SignForMac>
  <AppleRootCertificate>../Certificates/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer</AppleRootCertificate>
  <DeveloperIdCertificate>../Certificates/DeveloperIDCA.cer</DeveloperIdCertificate>
  <DeveloperIdP12>../Certificates/certificates.p12</DeveloperIdP12>
  <DeveloperIdAlias>KL596QNCVZ</DeveloperIdAlias>
  <DeveloperIdPassword> ... </DeveloperIdPassword>
</SignForMac>
```

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I know it's a few years back now but I have the same problem today. Anyone got an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to have your `.cer` and `.p12` files on disk somewhere (e.g. in a "`Certificates`" folder) and not just in the Keychain.

And then your XML configuration file will have entries [that look like this](http://www.jwrapper.com/sample-app-xml.html):

```
<SignForMac>
        <AppleRootCertificate>/Path/To/Certificates/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer</AppleRootCertificate>
        <DeveloperIdCertificate>/Path/To/Certificates/DeveloperIDCA.cer</DeveloperIdCertificate>
        <DeveloperIdP12>/Path/To/Certificates/DeveloperID.p12</DeveloperIdP12>
        <DeveloperIdAlias>my company dev key</DeveloperIdAlias>
        <DeveloperIdPassword>BlahBlahBlahBlah</DeveloperIdPassword>
</SignForMac>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I had followed the instructions on the page that I indicated and included the certificates as you mentioned. From the error, it seems to me the problem is the DeveloperIdAlias and not the certificates?

Comment: My problem is: I don't know what to insert for <my company dev key>

Comment: Look at the name of the certificate in your keychain.  For me, I see "Developer ID Application: Michael Dautermann".  Try that and see what happens.

Comment: Personally I tried that and it's not working. I tried different combinations without any luck. As always, Mac developers don't get much help...